# Undefined method `yield_content' for App

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app. Everything works well, but when I add this code:

```
   != yield_content :css
```

to a main view (template) or `"shared/_head"` directly

```
!!!5
%html{lang: :en}
  != haml :"shared/_head"
  != yield_content :css
  %body{'data-spy' => "scroll", 'data-target' => ".subnav", 'data-offset '=> "50"}
    != haml :"shared/_header"

    .container-fluid
      != haml :"shared/_flash"
      != yield
      %hr
      != haml :"shared/_footer"
```

the error throws:

```
undefined method `yield_content' for #<App:0x00000004267ce0>
```

Why is that?

Comment: Only this much is not enough... need more code to see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra-contrib#modular-style you just need to install the gem and then include content_for extension to your application file. Something like following:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/content_for'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  helpers Sinatra::ContentFor

  get '/' do
    erb :index
  end
end
```

Just have checked and it works for me

Comment: cannot load such file -- sinatra/content_for (LoadError)

Comment: sorry, forgot about required gem installation(when I wrote the answer the gem had been already installed on my comp). So I've updated my answer, please try